# Remove Polygon from the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Requirements: Using the Leaflet js maps api, when the customer clicks on a marker, a Rectangle should be drawn just below the Marker, centering according to the marker. Then clicking on another marker should remove previous rectangles and draw another rectangle below newly clicked marker.

Problem: I am using the code below to draw a polygon and I can see a rectangle. And it draws the rectangle on a marker. Then by clicking on another marker a new rectangle is being drawn. But the old rectangle also still exists.

Question: How should I implement the behavior, so that when clicking on new marker, the old rectangle will be deleted from the map?

```
 //polygon

var latBlockSize = 0.002;
var lngBlockSize = 0.002;
var route = [
      new L.LatLng(parseFloat(customer.MailingAddress.Lat) + latBlockSize, parseFloat(customer.MailingAddress.Lng) - lngBlockSize),
      new L.LatLng(parseFloat(customer.MailingAddress.Lat) + latBlockSize, parseFloat(customer.MailingAddress.Lng) + lngBlockSize),
      new L.LatLng(parseFloat(customer.MailingAddress.Lat) - latBlockSize, parseFloat(customer.MailingAddress.Lng) + lngBlockSize),
      new L.LatLng(parseFloat(customer.MailingAddress.Lat) - latBlockSize, parseFloat(customer.MailingAddress.Lng) - lngBlockSize)
   ];

window.polygon = new L.Polygon(route);

window.map.addLayer(window.polygon);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I figured it out by myself.

This was the solution:

```
window.map.removeLayer(window.polygon);
```

Comment: Works with L.rectangle too.

Comment: I have the same scenario. I want a marker to add polygon and remove polygon on giving area coordinates. For example, one office is in Australia handles near countries like South Africa etc. I want to click on the Australia marker then South Africa should highlight with polygon boundaries. when I click again it should remove the highlighted countries. Is that possible with leaflet and jquery toggle method.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That is working as well, tested with Leaflet 1.2.0.

`window.polygon.remove()`

Comment: Just what I needed, inside my update loop. I was adding another in each loop. Now I remove the previously before making a new one.